# How to declare a ValueBuilder object to be a StringSet when doing an UpdateItem in Dynamodb using gosdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

**NOTE**: Might seem like a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009687/append-to-or-create-stringset-if-it-doesnt-exist) but it's different because I need to do this via golang while that is in JS.

I want to do the following operation in goSDK on a dynamodb item:

```
 UpdateExpression: 'ADD socialAccounts :socialAccountId',
 ExpressionAttributeValues: {
   ':socialAccountId': {
      'SS': [socialAccountId]
    }
 },
```

Typically how that works out in GoSDK is:

```golang
expression.Add(expression.Name("socialAccounts"), expression.Value([]string{"socialAccountId"}))
```

However the SDK is not taking the array of strings as a `SS`(StringSet) type, but instead as a `L`(List) type.

Logged Error:

```
Error: ValidationException: Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator: ADD, operand type: LIST, typeSet: ALLOWED_FOR_ADD_OPERAND
```

I'm unable to find any functionality [in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/expression/) that specify how to mention a type.

Can anyone help?
Why I want to do it this way:

1. I want this to work even when the attribute `socialAccounts` does not exist.
2. I don't want to use the `SET` opearation with `list_append` because that can introduce duplicate elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dynamodb.AttributeValue` if you need to specify the type:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb/expression"
)

func main() {
    val := (&dynamodb.AttributeValue{}).SetSS(aws.StringSlice([]string{"socialAccountId"}))
    expression.Add(expression.Name("socialAccounts"), expression.Value(val))

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", val)
}
```

Output:

```
{
  SS: ["socialAccountId"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer @Zeke Lu 's answer over my own.
But the following is a "push-comes-to-shove" method that should accomplish everything.

```golang
updateExpr := "ADD #SOCIAL :SOCIAL"
expName := map[string]*string{"#SOCIAL": aws.String(SOCIAL)}
expVal := map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{":SOCIAL": {SS: aws.StringSlice(socialAccounts)}}

_, errUpdate = tablesConnection.UpdateItem(&dynamodb.UpdateItemInput{
    ExpressionAttributeNames:  expName,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: expVal,
    Key:                       key,
    TableName:                 aws.String(tableName),
    UpdateExpression:          aws.String(updateExpr),
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution uses the older Go AWS SDK. For Go SDK v2, the following has been working for me to circumvent the same problem.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb/types"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/dynamodb/expression"
)

func main() {
    val := (&types.AttributeValueMemberSS{Value: []string{"socialAccountId"}})
    expression.Add(expression.Name("socialAccounts"), expression.Value(val))

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", val)
}
```

People [have also had success with tags](https://thomasstep.com/blog/using-dynamodb-with-golang#string-sets), but I haven't managed to get that approach to work for my use case yet.